# How do I get started writing iPad, iTouch, and android apps using C#?

Tags: c#, android, ios, ipad, ide

Ok friends,  I'm a C# WPF .net developer and have been working pretty much exclusively with UI development in one language or another for the last 15 years.  The last 7 have been with C# and I have to admit that I am spoiled.

So, the question is:  How do I get started, and what tools are best to use?  I see that MonoTouch is out there, but it looks like it is now called Xamarin.  What about PhoneGap, Titanium, Appcelorator?  Are there others I haven't heard of yet?

I am just wanting to break into Android Development and/or iPad/iTouch development, but don't want to go native.  I would like to leverage my C# skills, preferably WPF, but I have no idea which tools support that for Android/iPad/iTouch development.

Which ones integrate with Visual Studio?

Anybody who has REAL EXPERIENCE with any of the above, or one that I haven't heard of, please chime in and point me in the right direction.

I really appreciate it.

Comment: Do it right. Go native.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the best technologies is the Mono for Android/iOS framework - specifically for the fact that you can target 3 platforms just by coding for the one. Of course UI is independent so you'll still need to learn each platforms Design patterns etc... But here

http://xamarin.com/?gclid=CM_agZWFgLYCFUvHtAodeDYADw

The best place to start

Answer (score 2):

Phonegap works by having a web view loading a html & javascript application, so, you wouldn't be using C#, and the results usually are a far shot from a native app.

In contrast, mono touch compiles your C# code so it can run natively on your mobile platform, and since they implement a wrapper around the native libraries you are suposed to be able to write applications as good as if you had gone native. On your case i think that would be pretty much the best way around.

By the way, Mono Touch doesn't remove the requirement of having a mac to develop iOS applications.

Answer (score 1):

If you're coming from WPF and familiar with the MVVM pattern you will find loads of js frameworks that share the same approach ([KnockoutJs](http://knockoutjs.com/) is a good one), basically this is what you'll be using if you want to go with a cross platform solution like PhoneGap wich is nothing more than wrapper for a webapp, and a few apis to access your device.

Personally I find PhoneGap a good solution only if you want to access the features of your device within a simple application. 
As soon you start to add pages to it the feeling lack of responsiveness will make you wonder why you didn't go native from the start.

Answer (score 1):

I would go for Xamarin. The Xamarin 2.0 has Visual Studio integration. You can write code for iOS or Android on Visual Studio 2012 (I am a ReSharper fan :) ).